# How to fix google chrome page Reloading issue on the opening of Developer tools

Tags: google-chrome

How to fix google chrome page Reloading issue on the opening of Developer tools when ever i open developers tools by pressing F12 or inspect element option chrome opens developer tools but it reloading the web page again..already reinstalled window & chrome but same problem

my chrome version: Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
installed extensions: ads block